# Why does .share() have no effect on cold sources (autoconnect vs. refCount)?

Tags: project-reactor

```
Flux<Integer> shared = Flux.just(1, 2).share();

shared.subscribe(System.out::println);
shared.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Since `share()` turns the flux into a hot one, I expect the first subscriber to get all values and the second one to get none, since the stream has completed at the time of subscription. But the output is the same as without `share`: `1 2 1 2`, but it should be just `1 2`.

When I replace `share()` with `publish.autoconnect()` it works as expected. Why is that?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is simple, but it took me a while to figure it out.

`share()` is a shortcut for `publish().refCount()`. `refCount()` is like `autoConnect()` except for one additional feature: It disconnects when all subscribers have cancelled or - and that's the situation here - the stream has completed.

The first `shared.subscribe` creates a subscription (via `share`) to the original flux. All values are emitted immediately, the stream completes, the subscription is cancelled.

Since there is no subscription now, the second `shared.subscribe` again creates a subscription and the stream starts again, from the beginning.

`autoConnect`, however, does not cancel the subscription. If you use it instead of `refCount` the subscription to the original flux remains, but because the stream has completed, any additional subscriber won't receive any values.